# Saving data from multiple forms in one page

Tags: python, django

I have a page that has two forms. One form appears as a popup after a user clicks the edit button.

I cannot save information from the form that pops up after clicking the edit button. Not sure what I am doing wrong.

This is what I have in views

```
def payment_view(request):
    form = MentorPaymentForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = MentorPaymentForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=request.user)
        if form.is_valid():
            user,mentor = form.save(commit=False)
            return redirect('teachers:payment_view')
    else:
        form = MentorPaymentForm(instance=request.user)
    return render(request, 'classroom/teachers/app-instructor-billing.html', {'form': form})
```

my template:

```
<form id="billing_details", method="post">
                        {% csrf_token %}
                          <label class="col-md-2 control-label">Account Number</label>
                          <div class="form-group form-control-material">
                            {{ form.account_num }}
                          </div>
                          <label for="bankname" class="col-md-2 control-label">Bank Name</label>
                          <div class="form-group form-control-material" id="bankname">
                            {{ form.bank_name }}
                          </div>
                          <label for="acc_num" class="col-md-2 control-label">Branch Code</label>
                          <div class="form-group form-control-material">
                            {{ form.branch_code }}
                          </div>
                          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success paper-shadow relative" data-z="0.5" data-hover-z="1" data-animated data-dismiss="modal">Update Payment Details</button>
                        </form>
```

and the edit button

```
                  <a href="#modal-update-credit-card" data-toggle="modal" class="btn btn-white btn-flat"><i class="fa fa-pencil fa-fw"></i> Edit</a>
```

here is what i have in urls

```
path('payment_view', teachers.payment_view, name='payment_view'),
```

**UPDATE**

as requested in the comments here is the full traceback when I remove commit=False

```
Traceback:

File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
  34.             response = get_response(request)

File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  115.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  113.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  21.                 return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  21.                 return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\djangoproject\django-multiple-user-types-example-master\django_school\classroom\views\teachers.py" in payment_view
  124.             user,mentor = form.save(commit=False)

File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py" in inner
  257.         return func(self._wrapped, *args)

Exception Type: TypeError at /teachers/payment_view
Exception Value: 'User' object is not iterable
```

and forms

```
class TeacherSignUpForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(max_length=100)
    first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    linkedin = forms.URLField(max_length=200)
    address = forms.CharField(max_length=500)
    billing_name = forms.CharField(max_length=200)
    account_num = forms.IntegerField()
    bank_name = forms.CharField(max_length=50)
    branch_code = forms.IntegerField()

    class Meta(UserCreationForm.Meta):
        model = User
        fields = ('email', 'username', 'first_name', 'last_name')

    def save(self, commit=True):
        self.instance.is_teacher = True
        user = super(UserCreationForm, self).save(commit=False)
        user.email = self.cleaned_data['email']
        user.first_name = self.cleaned_data['first_name']
        user.last_name = self.cleaned_data['last_name']
        user.save()
        mentor = Mentor.objects.get_or_create(
            user=user,
            linkedin=self.cleaned_data['linkedin'],
            address=self.cleaned_data['address'],
            billing_name=self.cleaned_data['billing_name'],
            account_num=self.cleaned_data['account_num'],
            bank_name=self.cleaned_data['bank_name'],
            branch_code=self.cleaned_data['branch_code'],
        )
        return user
...
class MentorPaymentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Mentor
        fields = ('address', 'billing_name', 'account_num', 'bank_name', 'branch_code')
```

Comment: Are forms related to each other? why don't you send request separately using javascript?

Comment: they are related. what do you mean?

Comment: ```user,mentor = form.save(commit=False)```
commit=False will get out a model object but it wont save it to db, You will need to call user.save() or mentor.save().. whatever is your case here, but this needs to happen.

Comment: you can submit the second form using ajax and similar to this link[https://dev.to/coderasha/how-to-send-django-form-with-ajax-4bpo] and save the object on the serverside using drf. if some kind of foreign key is needed you can first save the first form and set the fk using js in hidden fields of the form..

Comment: @MahsaMonavari getting page does not exist on link

Comment: try this :
https://dev.to/coderasha/how-to-send-django-form-with-ajax-4bpo

Comment: @KapilLamichhane doing that return the error 'User' object is not iterable

Comment: Need to see the full stack trace.

Comment: @KapilLamichhane updated question with the full traceback

Comment: ```124.             user,mentor = form.save(commit=False)```

Comment: @KapilLamichhane If I remove commit=False and just leave form.save nothing gets saved

Comment: Can i see the form class?

Comment: @KapilLamichhane I have added the form class to my question

Answer (score 0):

```
def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super(UserCreationForm, self).save(commit=False)
        user.is_teacher = True
        user.email = self.cleaned_data['email']
        user.first_name = self.cleaned_data['first_name']
        user.last_name = self.cleaned_data['last_name']

        mentor = Mentor.objects.get_or_create(
            user=user,
            linkedin=self.cleaned_data['linkedin'],
            address=self.cleaned_data['address'],
            billing_name=self.cleaned_data['billing_name'],
            account_num=self.cleaned_data['account_num'],
            bank_name=self.cleaned_data['bank_name'],
            branch_code=self.cleaned_data['branch_code'],
        )
        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user
```

`user,mentor = form.save(commit=False)` can be just `form.save()`

Answer (score 0):

I have a page with 4 forms, although technically I use it as 1 unique form (basic html), and then in "def post" I handle the request.POST.dict(), I set up a manual validation, according to the foreign keys, and I keep it where it belongs, but it's a simple form, not a modelform or django forms.

On the other hand, I recommend you to switch to CBV, it makes things easier for you, really FBV is tedious.